# How to get return error value of function? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I create async/await(try...catch) in new function.

and I call this function in another component.
then, I want to get only return error value and show error value.

How do I do it?

My Function:

```
const updateInformation = async () => {

try {
  const response = await updateAPI({
    variables: {
      data: {
        name: state.name,
        phoneNumber: state.phoneNumber,
      },
    },
  })
} catch (ex) {
  return Utils.extractErrorMessage(ex)
}
}
```

Component:

```
const onPressSendButton = () => {
if (name && address1 && address2 && phoneNum) {
  const r = updateInformation()
  // I want to show return error value in this line.
} else {
  return false
}
}
```

Comment: What is `updateAPI` means you are using `fetch` or something else?

Comment: @ravibagul91 `updateAPI` is mutation (apollo).

Comment: Somehow, you are not using this async function as you are intended to I guess. Since async functions always return a `promise`. So, either in the normal or `error` block, if you return something you get this as a promise resolve. So, where do you check if `updateAPI` throws an error in your code if resolving just the error is your true intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes, this should work (commented with explanations)  :

**Function**

```
const updateInformation = async () => {
    return updateAPI({ // Missing return
        variables: {
            data: {
                name: state.name,
                phoneNumber: state.phoneNumber,
            },
        },
    });
};
```

**Component**

```
const onPressSendButton = async () => {
    if (name && address1 && address2 && phoneNum) {
        try {
            const r = await updateInformation(); // Need to await here
        } catch (e) {
            // This is where you handle the error
        }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: `onPressSendButton` must be an async function also if you are using `await`.

Comment: Yep, well seen @devserkan

Comment: You're right @ravibagul91, actually useless in this case

Comment: Thank you for your solution! But, Can't `onPressSendButton` get the resolved result of `updateInformation` by returning error from `updateInformation`?

Comment: If you return the error from your function then you can get the result as @Nevroz suggested here I guess.